# (Proof clarification): Continuous functions on R must be Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, proof-explanation

I came across this proof that continuous functions on $\textbf{R}$ must be Lebesgue measurable (see Corollary 2.3.1, which I've written out (inexactly) below underneath the link):

http://www.applebaum.staff.shef.ac.uk/Ch2MeasFn.pdf

*Let $f : \textbf{R} \to \textbf{R}$ be continuous and O be an arbitrary open set in
R. Then, by the continuity of $f$,  $f^{-1}(O)$ is an open set in $\textbf{R}$. Then $f^{-1}(O)$
is in $\mathcal{B}(\textbf{R})$. Hence f is measurable.*

But I still don't understand it. Namely, given a function $f$,  what if the image set of $f$ is a closed set? Then the preimage of $f$ wouldn't necessarily be open, would it? Am I mistaken?

Comment: I encourage you to reproduce the proof here. It's a bit much to ask that others search through this entire document to find the proof you mention.

Comment: "[By] Theorem 2.2.2," to show that $f$ is measurable it is sufficient to show that for every open set $O\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. You don't need to consider the closed sets.

Comment: @ClementC.  I understood that part, but what I don't get is Proposition 2.3.1, which says that a function is continuous iff its preimage for every open set of R is open. But, what if R is NOT the image set of f? For example, what if f maps to a closed proper subset of R? Then it seems that the proof for Proposition 2.3.1 doesn't work, and consequently neither would the corollary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof goes as follows:

> **Theorem 2.2.2** *(paraphrased)*. a function $f\colon S\to\mathbb{R}$ (where $(S, \Sigma)$ is a measurable space) is $\Sigma$-measurable if, and only if, $f^{-1}(O)\in\Sigma$ for every open $O\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Apply this theorem to the continuous function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $(S,\Sigma)=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. To show $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, *it is therefore sufficient to consider only the open intervals $O\subseteq \mathbb{R}$*. This is what the proof does: pick an arbitrary $O\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, show that $f^{-1}(O)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Since $O$ was arbitrary, this holds for all of them, so Theorem 2.2.2 gives the conclusion.

You do **not** need to consider closed sets, at any point.

---

Following your comment on the original post, you seem to be concerned by the following point in the proof of Proposition 2.3.1 in the document you linked (which is the part that argues that if $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(O)$ is open for every open set $O$): *what if $O\cap f(\mathbb{R})=\emptyset$, i.e. $f^{-1}(O)=\emptyset$?*

Note that indeed their proof does not handle that. But it is then trivial to see that if $f^{-1}(O)=\emptyset$, since $\emptyset$ is indeed an open set, everything goes through.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please see my comment on the original post.

Comment: @Asker See my edit.

Comment: Wauw, it took me an embarrassingly long time to see that. Thank you very much for your help.